# .mesh to OBJ converter?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have a problem that is quite tricky to solve. I have a lot of cool models, but I can't export them into Blender because they're .mesh. I need to convert it to OBJ so Blender can read it, but to no avail.
In case you may wonder:
-XNALara doesn't work
-Any Windows program is useless to me as I have GNU/Linux and WINE does nothing.
So, please, if you have any suggestions on what to do, please tell me! I am pulling my hair out.

Comment: I have done a google search on your behalf using the search string
**".mesh batch convert to .obj"** it return a deviant website with
a software that has the ability to do batch convert. Here is the link http://3dgamemodels.deviantart.com/journal/how-to-convert-mesh-to-obj-332614828 As always make sure what you download is safe scan it down with your favorite
antivirus software. The latest version for 3d Converter is version 6.30 , they do have a trial version. I have not used it and do not know its limitations that may come with the trial license. Good luck.

Comment: use robloxstudio and replace a mesh file in there with your own mesh file(reliable)

Answer (score 1):

I installed that program, and even though it does provide for the conversion, it requires a registered version of it (ie. paid version). So far, I've only found ogre converter and a website that does mesh conversion (http://www.meshconvert.com/) to be reliable.

Comment: Creator of www.meshconvert.com here. Unfortunately meshconvert.com can't convert .mesh files yet. If anybody can hint me to a linux command line tool with this capability I will happily add this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

while trying(a lot), i figure it out how to open those .mesh that doesnt work with blender o XNAlara, use Noesis, right now its the only one that was able to read and properly display those model files. :D

depending where you find those models for example; mobile games if you find the _data files use UnityEX for exporting it would do all the hard work for you.